# Sending Javascript on applicationWillResignActive

Tags: javascript, ios

I'm trying to fire Javascript to a WebView when the home button is pressed.

So far, a simple

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webView finishing loading");

    NSString *title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]; 
    NSLog(@"result = %@", title);
}
```

works perfectly.

But the same code from

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

does nothing and `title` string is (null).

Comment: pressing home button call `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`method

Comment: no delegate method to run Javascript code when app goes into background.

Comment: Is this behavior documented by Apple?